# pip upgrade messed up python installation

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install a python application I wrote on a freshly created Ubuntu 16.4 virtual instance.  I need to install a number of python packages that I previously installed on my own PC.

Everything was going along swimmingly, until I saw this message:

```
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Okay, thinks I, this looks harmless enough.

However, after doing this, the next time I run pip, I get:

```
$ pip freeze
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

I thought I should revert to the old pip so

```
$ sudo apt install python-pip
```

and then

```
$ sudo apt install python-pip
...
Setting up python-pip (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) ...
```

OK, I've got pip 8.1.1 back.  But alas

```
$ pip freeze
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

So the question is what got screwed up by the upgrade of pip and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an extra pip in `/home/[name]/.local/bin/` ?

Comment: Thanks, but it was simpler for me to blow away the virtual ubuntu and start over.  I'll remember to check this next time.

Comment: Related question on SO: [ImportError: cannot import name main when running pip --version command in windows7 32 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210269/importerror-cannot-import-name-main-when-running-pip-version-command-in-windo)

Answer (score 3):

```
 $python -m pip uninstall pip
```

Use this and it will give you the previous pip version.

Answer (score 2):

Recently ran into the same issue with Ubunutu 16.04.

Notice when you do:

```
/usr/bin/pip freeze
```

You will get the Traceback error. When I ran which pip, I got the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

My shell was using `/usr/bin/pip` which was not the right one. I renamed `/usr/bin/pip` and symlinked the new one to where the old one was located:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip
```

Once I ran pip freeze, boom no more errors. I was able to see the packages installed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it worked, but I edited my /usr/bin/pip file and changed the offending line 7:

```
from pip import main
```

to

```
from pip._internal import main
```

and it this solved the issue.

I am using Ubuntu on Windows 10.

As mentioned in another answer, this was the difference between `/usr/local/bin/pip` and `/usr/bin/pip` in my machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall pip
```

This will fix the problem of incorrect pip being selected.